# Change temperature at which fan turns on?

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, cooling, temperature

I own a Razer Blade Stealth. Absolutely love it. Sometimes, however, the CPU temperature shoots over 80 degrees C, especially when watching videos full screen. I have done some research and found it is perfectly normal, because Razer does not allow their fans to turn on until the CPU gets past 90 degrees. That being said, sometimes I worry that the circuitry will get damaged from the intense heat and would like the fan to start at a lower CPU temperature, preferably around 75 degrees C. I tried to find some sort of BIOS setting, but there was nothing there. Is there any way to change this, maybe through Windows?
Thanks!

Comment: That is a safe temp to turn on the fans, if it is not in the bios, there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 1):

You need **SpeedFan**, if your system supports it. This will help you adjust the fan speed as required. You can also have a look at **MSI Afterburner**.

That said, if the manufacturer feels it is okay, no reason to be really worried!

Comment: This is Razer lol. They stuck in an i7 in a .5 inch chassis. is 90 degrees safe? the area near my vents gets super hot to the touch.